# Post intents using Dialogflow V2 REST API

Tags: json, rest, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to post intents using the V2 API. Using the payload below, the intent is correctly created but entities are not tagged.

In this example, I already posted the entity "drink" containing different types of beverage.
I know I am missing the "parameters" attributes, but I cant get it working properly to tag my entities.

```
{
    "displayName": "orderDrink",
    "webhookState": "WEBHOOK_STATE_ENABLED",
    "mlDisabled": false,
    "trainingPhrases": [
        {
            "name": "ac3fd328-518d-4f28-b5c1-c98d97b78874",
            "type": "EXAMPLE",
            "parts": [
                {
                    "text": "I would like a @drink"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "b6984288-3cbd-4c07-ac73-c7bf0ac87445",
            "type": "EXAMPLE",
            "parts": [
                {
                    "text": "@drink please"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help regarding the payload format to post intents would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just annotate individual words in a training phrase, you have to specify the text part and the entity part of a training phrase separately. That's why the `parts` key in the definition of a training phrase is a list. Your example would have to look like this:

```
{
    "displayName": "orderDrink",
    "webhookState": "WEBHOOK_STATE_ENABLED",
    "mlDisabled": false,
    "trainingPhrases": [
        {
            "name": "ac3fd328-518d-4f28-b5c1-c98d97b78874",
            "type": "EXAMPLE",
            "parts": [
                {
                    "text": "I would like a "
                },
                {
                    "text": "beer",
                    "entityType": "@drink",
                    "alias": "drink",
                    "userDefined": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "b6984288-3cbd-4c07-ac73-c7bf0ac87445",
            "type": "EXAMPLE",
            "parts": [
                {
                    "text": "beer",
                    "entityType": "@drink",
                    "alias": "drink",
                    "userDefined": true
                },
                {
                    "text": " please"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

See the [documentation](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/Shared.Types/Intent#trainingphrase) for the `TrainingPhrase` and specifically the `Part` objects in the Dialogflow REST API.

A good way to figure these things out is to define an intent in the Web UI, then export and download the agent and look at the resulting JSON file for this intent.

Comment: That's what I missed, it works perfectly now. Thanks a lot !